# Open_BaseDir function in plesk windows server not working

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012, plesk

i am trying to access files outside of domain root dir.

i know php can handle that.

please check following image:
[image]

i update/set in plesk to add the additional directory.

then i also check the .user.ini file, that folder is also there:

```
open_basedir="C:/Inetpub/vhosts/myDomain.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\;C:\DLoads\"
```

but still when i try to run my php file/script it throws following error:

```
PHP Warning:  filesize(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(c:\DLoads\Test.txt) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/myDomain.com\;C:\Windows\Temp\;C:\DLoads\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\myDomain.com\httpdocs\t5.php on line 3
```

below is my sample php script:

```
$file = 'c:\DLoads\Test.txt';
echo filesize($file);
```

so, what did i miss? what else setting i need to change to accept that?

is any ISS config missing?

thanks in advance

Comment: is there no difference between c:\ and C:\ ? :)

Comment: @MrSmile, thanks for your reply sir, but please notice that plesk also used C: (capital), though yes i have tried both... with no success.

Comment: Does it work if you set open_basedir as none?

Comment: @ElvisPlesky, nope that doesn't work either...

Comment: @Zakir_SZH Then maybe the issue can be more complex. Try to restore default permissions for the webspace directory (e.g. for example.com it will be C:\inetpub\vhosts\example.com\ ) Remove .Security file in webspace directory and execute this query from Command Prompt as administrator user ""%plesk_cli%\repair.exe" --repair-webspace-security -webspace-name example.com"